# How the getcwd is implemented in the kernel (library)?

Tags: c, directory, kernel, pwd

One process could do

```
chdir("/to/some/where");
```

when from the another shell

```
mv /to/some/where /now/different/path/
```

the 1st process

```
print getcwd(); 
#prints /now/different/path/
```

How the `getcwd` is implemented? (at the lowest level, e.g. at the level of kernel, inodes ...).

I know how common (inode based) filesystem works, e.g. what contains the directory (name of the entries and the corresponding inode numbers).

### EDIT

Probably the question was to vague - trying to refine it. One possible scenario (from what o knows)

1. the kernel knows the inode of the `CWD` for the given process (and his threads) - e.g. inode number `1000`
2. reads the inode (gets the blocks what needs to read)
3. reads the corresponding blocks (e.g. opens the directory)
4. read the directory entries (name of the entries and the inode numbers)
5. gets the inode number for the `..` parent directory (for example `900`) and the inode number of the `.` (current directory)
6. reads the content of the parent directory where gets

- the `name` of the previous directory (for the inode `1000`)
- the inode number of the parent directory

1. continue to `5.` - until the root inode is reached.

Thats mean, the `getcwd` for

```
/some/very/very/very/deep/directory/level
```

tooks more raw IO operations (more directory entries need to read) as for the short

```
/tmp
```

where the whole `getcwd` is done by two readings?

Is this correct? or it is done in totally another way?

Comment: Kernel of what OS? I'm guessing you're talking about one of the various variants of Unix, but... If you're talking about Linux, have you considered seeing what the source tells you?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm interesed in answer of the conceptual level, ofcourse mainly unix-like systems, (linux, freebsd) but if the windows do this with another (known) way - would be nice to know how... ;) Trying to find how it is implemented in many system calls in the milions of lines of kernel sources, is probably to hard for me. If do you know the answer, is too "hard" tell me? ;)

Comment: Would be nice to know what is wrong with this question, how i can show more research effort in this theme, e.g. what i can do to improve this question to avoid downvotes. ;)

Comment: Avoid dvotes? Asking on the right place. SO is for programming questions - and this question has not much with programming, but but because you asking for conceptual level - e.g. what could be "programming" -  i answered it.

Comment: The question was not too vague at all. I expected answers to encompass the entire set/volume of all possible variations of the question, and not just one ridiculously specific (and hence practically useless) case. Robot people usually demand the latter case, because they cannot think, and need to perform simple pattern matching on memorized knowledge. They cannot return a formula, because they don’t understand, but must return the list that they memorized.

Answer (score 1):

First, you asking on the wrong place. This question is more about the operating system, so the [unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com) is the better place.

Anyway, your proposed solution is *true* for some ancient UNIX implementation (for example BSD 2.8) or like. That pathname resolution could be done as you described.

However, many problems arises - few of them:

- as you said - too complicated pathname resolution (and yes, for the deeper directories needs more IO)
- depends on the premise that only ONE ROOT directory exists. This isn't true from the BSD 4.2 where are introduced the `per process` root directory - what allows the `chroot` system call - what allow sets the root to any directory without showing the real path to the process. (One of the coolest FreeBSD feature are the *jails* - depends on this) (Also ancient linuxes have only one root - only in the 0.96c are introduced the VFS - virtual filesystem layer)
- and permission problems - e.g. what happens when

```
#shell1
$ mkdir -p /tmp/some
$ cd /tmp/some
```

second shell

```
$ su
# mkdir -p /tmp/my
# chmod 700 /tmp/my
# mv /tmp/some /tmp/my/
```

the `/tmp/my` directory isn't readable for the first process. So, it can't determine the path, so how it should work with the files? So, in shell1 again:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/some #the original
$ echo $CWD
/tmp/some
$ /bin/pwd
pwd: .: Permission denied
```

But, you still can do for example

```
$ touch bob #works
```

e.g. the system allows you work in the "current" directory without let you know where are you. (in both scenarios e.g. in chroot and in the second one) ;)

That's mean than every process stores in his table the current working directory:

- device number (e.g. hdd1 or hdd2)
- inode number on the device

*and*

- the kernel maintains another global table(s), (in linux called as **dentry** (directory entries)), - where the kernel maintaining the "inode" -> "path" mapping for every process, every opened file descriptor, and also indode caches (in the linux maintained by the kernel itself, BSD: job for the `vnod` driver) and like.

E.g. when some process asks for the pathname for the inode X, the kernel searches the `dentry` table, if the entry found - return immediately, if not - calls the `lookup` process, what doing the *pathname resolution*.

When for example the rename occurs, the kernel searched the `dentry` table, if found the entry and changes it as needed.

All above is **extremely simplified**, as you can see yourself, all above is **highly** OS dependent, the common base is defined by POSIX - but happens behind (e.g. the implementation) - you need really read the sources of the kernel and/or google for:

- linux dentry
- linux vfs
- freebsd vnode
- pathname resolution

and such.

Ps: for the nitpickers, :) - as i said - everything is over-simplyfied, so if you want correct and add more details - edit the answer - i converted it to "community wiki answer".

Answer (score 0):

In current POSIX kernels like Linux (or *BSD-s) the current working directory (as a kernel inode) is part of the [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) state. So the in-kernel process descriptor (probably some `struct task_struct` on Linux) contains or refers to that cwd. Then `getcwd` is "simply" a syscall querying that.

The kernel inodes (for *opened* file descriptors, including working directories) are related to filesystems and are not the same as disk inodes.

<sup>Of course, the evil is in the details!</sup>

Comment: and this mean, if another process moves the directory to another place, the kernel (at the rename) searches his tables for every process (and thread) and changes the state?

Comment: Edited the question - the inode doesn't contains the `name`, nor the `path`.

Comment: Kernel inodes (for opened file descriptors, including current working directories) are not disk inodes.

Comment: E.g. the `kernel inodes` is something what is different of the `filesystem inodes` and they contains the full path name for the given `kernel inode`. And when **any** process doing file oparation, such `rename (mv)` the kernel searches this `kernel inode table` and changes the stored `path` to the new value for every opened descriptor what poins the the given inode? (would be nice if you could edit the answer for the _evil details_. :)

Comment: You need to read several entire books about Unix internals and Operating System principles. I don't have time to explain them to you.

Answer (score 0):

Key point: chdir() only affects the current process and any child processes launched after that - it is not a global state.